# Fill incomplete time series in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

**Question:** In `data.table` is there any way to fill an incomplete date sequence with zeros? For instance, in the toy example some dates does not show up and I want to have a complete date sequence with `y = 0` for these cases. Is there something like a forward fill?

**Remark:** Note I do not want to use merges where you create first the full date sequence and then merge it back to the initial data.table object (I think this is inefficient and rather slow).

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c("2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-05"),
  y = c(1, 5, 3, 70)
)

## Output:
            x  y
1: 2020-03-28  1
2: 2020-03-29  5
3: 2020-03-31  3
4: 2020-04-05 70

## Desired Output:
            x  y
1: 2020-03-28  1
2: 2020-03-29  5
3: 2020-03-30  0
4: 2020-03-31  3
5: 2020-04-01  0
6: 2020-04-02  0
7: 2020-04-03  0
8: 2020-04-04  0
9: 2020-04-05 70
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CJ` and `tidyr::full_seq` to create a join data table.

```
dt[, x := as.Date(x)]                               # convert x to the Date type
dt2 <- dt[CJ(x = tidyr::full_seq(x, 1)), on = .(x)] # create the full sequence
dt2[is.na(y), y := 0]                               # fill NAs with 0s
dt2

#             x  y
# 1: 2020-03-28  1
# 2: 2020-03-29  5
# 3: 2020-03-30  0
# 4: 2020-03-31  3
# 5: 2020-04-01  0
# 6: 2020-04-02  0
# 7: 2020-04-03  0
# 8: 2020-04-04  0
# 9: 2020-04-05 70
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
# convert to data.table's integer date type
dt[ , x := as.IDate(x)]
# find the range of dates
date_bounds = range(dt$x)
# construct a sequence of all dates
#   NB: this will be integers as attributes are stripped
all_dates = date_bounds[1L]:date_bounds[2L]

# construct a table with the missing dates,
#   with y filled to 0
missing = data.table(
  # as.IDate uses the right origin for integer input
  x = as.IDate(setdiff(all_dates, dt$x)),
  y = 0
)

dt = rbind(dt, missing)
#             x     y
#        <IDat> <num>
# 1: 2020-03-28     1
# 2: 2020-03-29     5
# 3: 2020-03-31     3
# 4: 2020-04-05    70
# 5: 2020-03-30     0
# 6: 2020-04-01     0
# 7: 2020-04-02     0
# 8: 2020-04-03     0
# 9: 2020-04-04     0
```

Afterwards you can `setorder(dt, x)` if you want the dates to be in order

Answer (score 0):

You could use `complete` from `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(x = as.Date(x)) %>%
  complete(x = seq(min(x), max(x), by = "day"), fill = list(y = 0))

#     x           y
#  <date>     <dbl>
#1 2020-03-28     1
#2 2020-03-29     5
#3 2020-03-30     0
#4 2020-03-31     3
#5 2020-04-01     0
#6 2020-04-02     0
#7 2020-04-03     0
#8 2020-04-04     0
#9 2020-04-05    70
```

Comment: thanks, problem here is that a `tibble` is returned and I want to keep it in `data.table` framework (and I do not want to use `as.data.table` over and over). I thought there is a convinience function in `data.table` for this task

Comment: If you don't want to create a full sequence of dates and then merge, I am not aware about any other method which does that in `data.table`. Maybe some `data.table` expert would know that.

Comment: This still seems to do the merge

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
dt[, x := as.IDate(x)]
dt[.(seq(min(x), max(x), 1)), .(y = fifelse(is.na(y), 0, y)), .EACHI, on = "x"]

#             x     y
# 1: 2020-03-28     1
# 2: 2020-03-29     5
# 3: 2020-03-30     0
# 4: 2020-03-31     3
# 5: 2020-04-01     0
# 6: 2020-04-02     0
# 7: 2020-04-03     0
# 8: 2020-04-04     0
# 9: 2020-04-05    70
```